# Model parallelism, CUDA out of memory in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, out-of-memory

I am trying to  build autoencoder model, where input/output is RGB images with size of 256 x 256. I tried to train model on 1 GPU with 12 GB of memory but I always caught CUDA OOM (I tried differen batchsizes and even batch size of 1 is failing). So I read about model parallelism in Pytorch and tried this:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_output_size):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_output_size, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(1024, 200),
            nn.ReLU(True)
            ).cuda(0)
      
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Linear(200, 1024),
           nn.ReLU(True),
           nn.Linear(1024, input_output_size),
           nn.Sigmoid()).cuda(1)
        
        print(self.encoder.get_device())
        print(self.decoder.get_device())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.cuda(0)
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = x.cuda(1)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
```

So I have moved my encoder and decoder on different GPUs. But now I get this exception:

```
Expected tensor for 'out' to have the same device as tensor for argument #2 'mat1'; but device 0 does not equal 1 (while checking arguments for addmm)
```

It appear when I do x = x.cuda(1) in forward method.

Moreover, here is my "train" code, maye you can give me some advices about optimizations? Is images of 3 x 256 x 256 too large for training? (I cannot reduce them). Thank you in advance.

Training:

```
input_output_size = 3 * 256 * 256
model = Autoencoder(input_output_size).to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

for epoch in range(100):
    epoch_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (images, _) in enumerate(dataloader):
        images = torch.flatten(images, start_dim=1).to(device)
        output_images = model(images).to(device)
        train_loss = criterion(output_images, images)
            
        
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch_idx % 5 == 0:
            with torch.no_grad():
                model.eval()
                pred = model(test_set).to(device)
                model.train()

                test_loss = criterion(pred, test_set)

                wandb.log({"MSE train": train_loss})
                wandb.log({"MSE test": test_loss})
                del pred, test_loss

        if batch_idx % 200 == 0:
            # here I send testing images from output to W&B
            with torch.no_grad():
                model.eval()
                pred = model(test_set).to(device)
                model.train()
                wandb.log({"PRED": [wandb.Image((pred[i].cpu().reshape((3, 256, 256)).permute(1, 2, 0) * 255).numpy().astype(np.uint8), caption=str(i)) for i in range(20)]})
                del pred
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        epoch_loss += train_loss.item()
        del output_images, train_loss
    epoch_loss = epoch_loss / len(dataloader)
    wandb.log({"Epoch MSE train": epoch_loss})
    del epoch_loss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues that I'm seeing:

---

```
model(test_set)
```

This is when you are sending *the entirety of your test set* (presumably huge) as a single batch through your model.

---

I don't know what `wandb` is, but another likely source of memory growth is these lines:

```
wandb.log({"MSE train": train_loss})
wandb.log({"MSE test": test_loss})
```

You seem to be saving `train_loss` and `test_loss`, but these contain not only the numbers themselves, but the computational graphs (living on the GPU) needed for backprop. Before saving them, you want to convert them into `float` or `numpy`.

---

Your model contains two `3*256*256 x 1024` weight blocks. When used in Adam, these will require `3*256*256 x 1024 * 3 * 4 bytes` = 2.25GB of VRAM **each** (Possibly more, if it's inefficiently implemented) This looks like a poor architecture for other reasons also.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The size of my test set is only 426 images and even if I remove test evaluating part I still get 8 GB used on the first epoch. I am using pytorch 1.7.0

Comment: @anon1453092865 No OOM. That's progress. See the update also.

Comment: I get OOM bit not on the first iteration. But the point with losses is good, I fixed it but it seems like there is no effect. And I still do it only with batches of size 1.

Comment: I have noticed that if I run my training loop without loss.backward() I will consume only 2,5 Gb. And I get OOM exactly on that line

Comment: wandb is online service for watching training process. So I do not save anything locally and as I said, when I have removed the lines with test predictions nothing has changed.

Comment: @anon1453092865 *"wandb is online service for watching training process. So I do not save anything locally"*. Just because it's online doesn't mean that it's not holding on to the data while the program runs. If you are still seeing an OOM after fixing these, you should post a minimal reproducible example (replace your images with `torch.randn(3, 256, 256)` ) something people can run without having to guess what you did, or having access to your data.

Comment: @anon1453092865 See the 3rd update

Comment: yes, I think you are right about model parameters and its sizes. I just wanted to try vanilla autoencoder first and convolutional autoencoder then, but it looks like vanilla is not appropriate for such "big" images. I will try to use Conv layers. Thx.

Comment: and what about model parallelism? why is it not working?